# ¿Cómo llamo correctamente variables de API a Swift?

Tags: json, swift

buenas noches. Estoy teniendo problemas para 'referenciar' mi API.
Explico:
Tengo un archivo llamado "profile" donde quiero mostrar los datos del usuario.
**No tengo ni la más mínima idea del cómo llamar al nombre, apellidos y demás datos necesarios para mostrar en el perfil.**

He estado divagando por distintos tutoriales y no encuentro una respuesta certera.

Dejo el archivo acá:

```
@ObservedObject var networkingManager = NetworkingManager()
 

var body: some View {

    ScrollView
    {

        
        
            VStack (alignment: .center)
            {
                VStack
                {
                    Text("Perfil")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.top)
                    Image("SafeVet")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .padding(.top,5)
                        .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    
                    HStack
                    {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("Nombre")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    
                                }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                        
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        
                    }.padding(1)
                    .padding(.leading,15)
                    
                    HStack 
                    {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                {
                                    VStack
                                    {
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                        **Text(networkingManager.userList.data.nombre)** <--- ERROR
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                        
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        
                    }.padding(.bottom,15)
                    .padding(.leading,15)
                    
                    VStack
                    {
                        HStack
                        {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                    {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("Apellido")
                                            .font(.title3)
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        
                                    }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                            
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        }.padding(1)
                        .padding(.leading,15)
                        
                        HStack
                        {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12, content:
                                    {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(" Vazquez Hernandez")
                                            .font(.title3)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        
                                    }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                            
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        }.padding(.bottom,15)
                        .padding(.leading,15)
                        
                        HStack
                        {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12, content:
                                    {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("Teléfono")
                                            .font(.title3)
                                            .bold()
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        
                                    }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                            
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        }.padding(1)
                        .padding(.leading,15)
                        
                        HStack
                        {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                    {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("6673366491")
                                            .font(.title3)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        
                                    }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                            
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        }.padding(.bottom,15)
                        .padding(.leading,15)
                        
                        HStack
                        {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                    {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("Fecha de nacimiento")
                                            .font(.title3)
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        
                                    }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                            
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        }.padding(1)
                        .padding(.leading,15)
                        
                        VStack {
                            HStack
                            {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("17 - 01 - 98")
                                                .font(.title3)
                                                
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            
                                        }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                
                                Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                
                            }.padding(.bottom,15)
                            .padding(.leading,15)
                            
                            HStack
                            {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("Correo")
                                                .font(.title3)
                                                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            
                                        }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                
                                Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                
                            }.padding(1)
                            .padding(.leading,15)
                            
                            HStack
                            {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("bryan@bryan.com")
                                                .font(.title3)
                                                
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            
                                        }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                
                                Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                
                            }.padding(.bottom,15)
                            .padding(.leading,15)
                            
                            HStack
                            {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("Sexo")
                                                .font(.title3)
                                                .bold()
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            
                                        }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                
                                Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                
                            }.padding(1)
                            .padding(.leading,15)
                            
                            
                            HStack
                            {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content:
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("Masculino")
                                                .font(.title3)
                                                
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            
                                        }).padding(.horizontal,10)
                                
                                
                                Spacer(minLength: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                
                            }.padding(1)
                            .padding(.leading,15)
                            
                            Text("")
                        }
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }.background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(50)
                .padding(.horizontal,30)
                .padding(.vertical,100)
                .shadow(radius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
                
                
                
                
                Spacer()
                
            }.background(Color("blue"))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
        
        }.background(Color("blue"))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    
    
 
    

        
    
}

struct Profile_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Profile()
    }
}
```

}

Ya tengo definida la estructura de mi JSON:

```
import Foundation


// MARK: - Empty
struct UserList : Decodable{
    let data: [UserListStruct]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct UserListStruct : Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let clienteID: Int?
    let nombre, apellido, fechaNacimiento, usuario: String
    let contraseña, telefono, correo: String?
    let v: Int?
    let creado, estatus: String?
    let mascotas: [String]
    let sexo: String?
    let domicilio: Domicilio?
}

// MARK: - Domicilio
struct Domicilio :Decodable {
    let estado, ciudad, numero, codigoPostal: String?
    let colonia, calle: String?
}
```

Y por ultimo tengo mi "NetworkingManager" para conectarme con mi API:

```
    //
//  NetworkingManager.swift
//  SafeVet
//
//  Created by Bryan Vázquez on 24/05/21.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject {
    
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkingManager, Never>()  //enviar y recibir información , never no retorna nada
    
    @Published var userList = UserList(data: [])
    {
        //property observers: 'funcion' que ejecuta algo cuando nuestras variables cambian de valor
        didSet
        {//se ejecuta cuando la variable ya cambió
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    
    init()
    {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/api/clientes") else { return  }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, _) in
            
            if let response = response{
                print(response)
            }
            do
            {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserList.self, from: data)
              print(users)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.userList = users
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("No funciona la API", error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

La pregunta es:
¿Cómo hago para poder poner el nombre de mi archivo JSON en mi vista de perfil? He buscado por todas partes y no sé como hacerlo :(

Comment: La pregunta es igual que la anterior que hiciste?

Comment: No, es diferente.

Comment: Quieres acceder a la variable `users` del `NetworkingManager` para mostrar los datos del `json`?

Comment: Asi es, eso es lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás haciendo el llamado a la clase `NetworkingManager()`. Como no tengo acceso a tu servidor local y tampoco a la respuesta json; te dejo este ejemplo con otra url. Tengo esta clase para recibir el json:

```
class Test: Codable {
    var args: Args?
    var headers = [String: String]()
    var origin: String = ""
    var url: String = ""
    
    required init(_ values: [String: Any]) { }
}

struct Args: Codable { }
```

El json de la url `"https://httpbin.org/get"` es el siguiente:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en,es-ES;q=0.9,es;q=0.8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\"", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-60ad245b-1731b5b7616088e349278bee"
  }, 
  "origin": "200.125.250.114", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Para entender mejor el funcionamiento de las llamadas a las API, deberías trabajar con `completionHandler`, que te permiten enviar la respuesta después de llenarse los datos. Puedes tener esta función para hacer la llamada a la API y el manejo de la respuesta en json:

```
func load(completion: @escaping ([Test]) -> ()) {//Función con el parámetro completion
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get") else {//la url es de ejemplo
        return
    }

    //Aquí llamas a la url y recibes el json en tu estructura

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        let testDecoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.test.append(testDecoded)
                completion(self.test)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Ahora haces el llamado al objeto `NetworkingManager` que lo puedes hacer en el método `.onAppear()`

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
             //Llamas a la función .load() y esperas a recibir la respuesta.
             NetworkingManager().load { testResponse in
                 self.test = testResponse

                 if self.test.count > 0 {
                     //Aquí accedes a los miembros de la clase del objeto json ya transformado.
                     print(self.test[0].args)
                     print(self.test[0].headers)
                     print(self.test[0].origin)
                     print(self.test[0].url)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

Al ejecutar el programa te imprime:

```
Optional(networking.Args())
["Host": "httpbin.org", "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-60ad22bc-135b2d473e4d25c11acf31e3", "Accept-Language": "en-us", "Accept": "*/*", "User-Agent": "networking/1 CFNetwork/1220.1 Darwin/20.3.0", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"]
165.225.35.30
https://httpbin.org/get
```

Este sería el código completo

**NetworkingManager.swift**

```
import Foundation

class Test: Codable {
    var args: Args?
    var headers = [String: String]()
    var origin: String = ""
    var url: String = ""
    
    required init(_ values: [String: Any]) { }
}

struct Args: Codable { }

class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var test = [Test]()
    
    func load(completion: @escaping ([Test]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get") else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            let testDecoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.test.append(testDecoded)
                completion(self.test)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var test = [Test]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onAppear() {
                NetworkingManager().load { testResponse in
                    self.test = testResponse

                    if self.test.count > 0 {
                        print(self.test[0].args)
                        print(self.test[0].headers)
                        print(self.test[0].origin)
                        print(self.test[0].url)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```